# How can i use if-else condition inside for loop?

Tags: java

How can i use if-else condition inside for loop?if condition run five times and else condition run only one time not five time.

When if condition is true.for loop execute five times.when if condition is wrong 
.for loop run only one time....

this my code..
suppose ff.size=5

```
for (int c = 0; c<ff.size(); c++) {
    if(mStreet.getText().toString().equals(ff.get(c).name)) {
        mActivity.finishActivityWithResult(mCurrentId);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Delivery Address not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you have so far ?

Comment: Please show the code you are having difficulty with.

Comment: Don't tag spam for visibility. I assume you're not writing this in BOTH `C` and `java`. Pick one. Additionally, this is an incredibly basic question. You should pick up an introductory book for whatever language you're using which will almost assuredly cover loops and conditions.

Comment: Show your code, and explain why you think it's wrong, please.

Comment: `if (!condition) { break; }`

Comment: Thank you for improving your question. But can you explain what doesn't work in that code? What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pseudo-code for you

```
count = 1
begin for : 
    if(condition)
        increment count by 1
        // do something...
        if (increment > 5)
            // do something...
            break //or return
    else
        // do something...
        break //or return
end of for
```

**EDIT:** Use `break` in your `else` block. The [break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#break_statement) statement breaks out of the closest loop.

```
for (int c = 0; c<ff.size(); c++) {
    if(mStreet.getText().toString().equals(ff.get(c).name)) {
        mActivity.finishActivityWithResult(mCurrentId);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Delivery Address not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break; // this will terminate your loop
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect rakeb or anyone else to help if that's all the information you give? "not working" is a terrible description of the problem. *How* is it not working?

Comment: @john. you sure, the `break` statement _failed_ to break the loop?

Comment: @rakeb.void your answer is right but in my case its wrong

Comment: I'm sorry john, if you are still facing problem with your code, then I'm pretty much sure, there are other problems instead of what you post. So better you create another thread or edit here the full problematic or buggy code, and explain what is wrong. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

in the else statment add a `break;`